# Bayesian imputation model for day of month when the year, month, and day of week are available

Tags: time-series, bayesian, stochastic-processes, data-imputation

I'm considering including vehicle incident data paired to date, however the most extensive data for the region I am interested in does not have dates. I would like to include it in a multivariable forecast with one of the variables being "number of incidents". The dataset is [ICBC Reported Crashes](https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/icbc/viz/ICBCReportedCrashes/ICBCReportedCrashes) if you want to look in more detail.

An issue I have with using this data is that it does not provide information at the resolution of date. Rather it provides:

- Year (e.g. 2018)
- Month (e.g. November)
- Day of week (e.g. Friday)
- Time intervals (e.g. 07:00 PM - 8:00 PM)

Naturally, the piece of information I am missing is the day of month in order to construct dates.

My first thinking on a modelling approach (but not a specific model) is to assume that there is partial pooling across time. That is if there is some combination of seasonality across months and a maybe even a trend across years, that might give indirect information about *which Friday* of November 2018 an incident was more likely to occur on. So I am guessing something like a Poisson process measurement with its mean varying according to something like a log-Gaussian process. Even more complicated, there may be spatial autocorrelation that motivates using a spatio-temporal stochastic process, but I should consider some simpler alternatives first as recommended by [Gelman *et al* 2020](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.01808).

I also think using the day of week in coordination with the month/year is important as it narrows down the number of possibility dates to just a few (e.g. 4 or 5).

What model structure might be suitable for estimating posterior probabilities for the dates when each incident occurred in this data set?

(I'll be building the model with probabilistic programming tools, so don't fret if a model seems like a good idea but doesn't have an available package that implements it.)

Comment: "I'm considering including vehicle incident data paired to date" - including it in what? What's your goal? 
From the data you described it might be possible to infer incident probabilities hierarchically for year, month and day of week.  By that you can capture certain temporal effects regarding traffic, like packed rush hours (time of day) , weeks/months with increased vacation traffic (week/month of year) etc. . While day of month could be interesting in this regard, e.g. for the effect of particular holidays, what's your motivation for trying to impute the data down to that level?

Comment: @deemel "*what's your motivation for trying to impute the data down to that level?*" The other variables are specified to the date, and I don't want to throw away information by aggregating them if I can help it.